# Jpql not getting null values with two level fetches

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Following code getting only projectId = 1 records but also wish account null ones. I am missing something?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT M FROM Message M WHERE M.account IS NULL OR M.account.project.id = 1")
List<Message> findMessages();
```

this one gets true result.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT M FROM Message M WHERE M.account IS NULL")
List<Message> findMessages();
```

also true result

```
@Query(value = "SELECT M FROM Message M WHERE M.account IS NULL OR M.account.id = 1")
List<Message> findMessages();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is JPQL null issue with join.

This is alternative solution , fixed and applied for my other complex script.
Anyway appreciated if explain the base reason of this issue.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT M FROM Message M LEFT JOIN M.account A WHERE M.account IS NULL OR A.project.id = 1")
```

List findMessages();

Comment: the reason is that jpa implicit join is inner join. with inner join you keep only records that have matching values in both tables. the solution is using left join because you always want to select the left even when there is no right value https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types#1-implicit-inner-join-with-single-valued-association-navigation